# Use Inner Query in DBCC checkident

Tags: sql, sql-server

as I'm aware, the DBCC checkident uses three parameters as below:

```
DBCC checkident('myTable', reseed, id_to_reset)
```

I wish to use a sub query to get the third parameter i.e. id_to_reset, something like below:

```
DBCC checkident('myTable', reseed, SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Id),0) FROM myTable2)
```

As of now, SQL Server throws syntax error but I'm sure there must be some way to do this.I know I can do that using a variable and pass in checkident but that's what I want to avoid for some reason.[image]

Comment: What is your reason for avoiding using a variable?

Comment: First, I want to reduce lines of code. Second, I wish to the use the DBCC checkident multiple time in same query for many tables to I would have to rename the variables each time i use DBCC command. I believe there are always scope for code improvements...

Comment: First, sacrificing readability to save 1 line of code is a bad practice. Second, don't make a bunch of variables, but write over the 1 original one by setting it to a new value and then reuse the variable. You are talking about adding a trivial amount of lines of code in order to make your app work and it will be clean and readable. Unless you are playing code golf, make your code understandable instead of slamming everything into one line. Lastly, why are you reseeding identities on so many tables?

Comment: I understand what you want to conclude and finally I wish to know is there a way to use sub query. I'm surprised you voted the question as negative and haven't provided the answer yet.

Comment: Did you try putting the subquery in parens?

Comment: @TabAlleman Still syntax errors.

Comment: Then I think you've answered your own question.   It is not possible.

Comment: Can you guys please explain the reason for voting negative for the question? I'll keep that in mind while asking the questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your value into a variable first:

```
DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Id),0) FROM myTable2)

DBCC checkident('myTable', reseed, @id)
```

If you need to reseed multiple tables, you can overwrite the variable as you go:

```
DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Id),0) FROM myTable2)

DBCC checkident('myTable', reseed, @id)

SET @id = (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Id),0) FROM myTable3)
DBCC checkident('myTable3', reseed, @id)
```